# Resolving conflicts in methods calling functions with the same name in C++

Tags: c++, name-conflict

Consider the following stripped-down example of a (templated) C++ structure for square matrices (it doesn't need to be templated for the problem to occur):

```
#include <array>
#include <complex>
using namespace std;

double conj (double &x) { return x; };

template <typename T, int N>
struct matrix: array<T,N*N> {
    void conj() {
        for (int ij=0; ij<100; ++ij) {
            T z = (*this)[ij];
            (*this)[ij] = conj(z);
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    matrix<double,10> a;
    a.conj();
    return 0;
}
```

I want to implement a method that performs matrix complex conjugation, using the name .conj() to coincide with the naming system used in the < complex > library. However, I get the following error:

```
$ g++ example.cpp -std=c++11
example.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void matrix<T, N>::conj() [with T = double; int N = 10]’:
example.cpp:19:12:   required from here
example.cpp:12:26: error: no matching function for call to ‘matrix<double, 10>::conj(double&)’
      (*this)[ij] = conj(z);
                          ^
example.cpp:12:26: note: candidate is:
example.cpp:9:10: note: void matrix<T, N>::conj() [with T = double; int N = 10]
     void conj() {
          ^
example.cpp:9:10: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

The compiler doesn't seem to recognize the *function* conj(double&) called inside the method of the same name, and defined before the structure. Instead, it tries to call the *method* conj().

Why isn't the compiler able to resolve this naming conflict, and what would be the solution that preserves the naming? Of course, if I change the name of the method to something different to conj, the code compiles and runs normally.

Comment: Use the [scope operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_resolution_operator), Luke: `(*this)[ij] = ::conj(z);`

Comment: In your main function you are calling a.conj() instead of conj(double &x). When you have two or more functions with the same name, C++ will make functions calls based on the # of input parameters. You should call them according to their parameters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The member function hides functions of the same name in a wider scope.

Use the qualified name `::conj` to refer to the function in the global namespace.

Comment: Such a simple and elegant solution. Thank you, Mike! I never thought the scope operator :: could be used with nothing on its left hand side.

Comment: @helvio: With nothing on the left-hand side, it specifies the global namespace (which doesn't have a name).

Comment: Following the error, does that means the compiler thinks this is a recursive function call? If that is the case, this would have lead into an infinite loop.

Comment: @Juniar: No, the compiler can't find an overload taking `double` (since it's hidden by the member function), so fails to compile it. If both functions had the same signature, then you'd get a recursive call  rather than a compile error.

Comment: That make sense, so it never get called anyway. However, it looks like a run time error, since both functions are declared within the same class.

Comment: @Juniar: No, the question clearly states the compile-time error. They're not both declared within the same class; one is a member of `matrix`, while the other is a non-member in the global namespace.